# Boolean method not returning in different situations [RUBY]

Tags: ruby, methods, boolean

I'm building a simple web-scraper (scraping jobs from indeed.com) for practice and I'm trying to implement the following method (low_salary?(salary)). The aim is for the method to compare a minimum (i.e. desired) salary, compare it with the offered salary contained in the job object (@salary):

```
class Job

  attr_reader :title, :company, :location, :salary, :url

  def initialize(title, company, location, salary, url)
    @title = title
    @company = company
    @location = location
    @salary = salary
    @url = url
  end

  def low_salary?(minimum_salary)
    return if !@salary

    minimum_salary < @salary.split(/[^\d]/)[1..2].join.to_i
  end

end
```

The method works fine when comapring @salary and the min_salary variable given to it, the delete_if appropriately deletes the elements that return true for low_salary? and returns correctly when @salary is nil (indeed listings don't always include the salary so my assumption is that there will be some nil values) in the following test program (Also: I am unsure as to why minimum_salary < @salary works but @salary < minimum_salary doesn't, but this does exactly what I want it to do):

```
require_relative('job_class.rb')
job = Job.new("designer", "company", "location", "£23,000 a year", "url")
job_results = []
job_results.push(job)

min_salary = 50000

print job.low_salary?(min_salary)

job_results.delete_if { |job| job.low_salary?(min_salary) }

print job_results
```

However in my scraper program, I get a no method error when calling the method: job_class.rb:16:in "low_salary?": undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require_relative 'job_class.rb'

class JobSearchTool

  def initialize(job_title, location, salary)
    @document = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://uk.indeed.com/jobs?q=#{job_title.gsub('-', '+')}&l=#{location}"))
    @job_listings = @document.css('div.mosaic-provider-jobcards > a')
    @salary = salary.to_i
    @job_results = []
  end

  def scrape_jobs
    @job_listings.each do |job_card|
        @job_results.push(Job.new(
          job_card.css('h2 > span').text, #title
          job_card.css('span.companyName').text, #company
          job_card.css('div.companyLocation').text, #location
          job_card.css('span.salary-snippet').text, #salary
          job_card['href']) #url
        )
    end
  end

  def format_jobs
    @job_results.each do |job|
      puts <<~JOB
        #{job.title} - #{job.company} in #{job.location} :#{job.salary}
        Apply at: #{job.url}
        ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      JOB
    end
  end

  def check_salary
    @job_results.delete_if { |job| job.low_salary?(@salary) }
  end
  
  def run
    scrape_jobs

    check_salary

    format_jobs
  end

if __FILE__ == $0
  job_search_tool = JobSearchTool.new(ARGV[0], ARGV[1], ARGV[2])
  job_search_tool.run
end
```

Obviously something from the scraper programme is influencing the method somehow, but I can't understand what it could be. I'm using the method in the exact same way as the test program, so what difference is causing the method not to return when @salary is nil?

Comment: The last question I felt was unnecessary to leave up since it was an oversight of the operator. This one is more than that so I'm leaving it up to be resolved as there's clearly some aspect I don't understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on the URL you're scraping shows there are job posts that don't have a salary, so, when you get the data from that HTML element and initialize a new Job object, the salary is an empty string, and knowing that `"".split(/[^\d]/)[1..2]` returns nil, that's the error you get.

You must add a way to handle job posts without a salary:

```
class Job
  attr_reader :title, :company, :location, :salary, :url

  def initialize(title, company, location, salary, url)
    @title = title
    @company = company
    @location = location
    @salary = salary.to_s # Explicit conversion of nil to string
    @url = url
  end

  def low_salary?(minimum_salary)
    return if parsed_salary.zero? # parsed_salary returns always an integer,
                                  # so you can check when is zero,
                                  # and not just when is falsy

    minimum_salary < parsed_salary
  end

  private

  def parsed_salary
    salary[/(?<=£)(\d|,)*(?=\s)/]
      .to_s        # converts nil to "" if the regex doesn't capture anything
      .tr(",", "") # removes the commas to parse the string as an integer
      .to_i        # parses the string to its corresponding integer representation
  end
end
```

Notice the regex isn't meant to capture everything, but it works with the salary as rendered in the website.

Comment: You're not validating against nil values that way, that's a truthyness comparison, and `!""` returns false, so the guard clause isn't being executed. If you want to avoid that problem you can check if the `@salary` variable is nil or is an empty string.

Comment: Than you for this Sebastian Palma. I had tried doing this with "@salary2 (i.e. if "@salary" == nil || "@salary".empty?). Using .empty? seems to work as well but given what I want to do with the tool I will try using the method in the answer. Unfortunately I still get listings that do  not match the given salary but I think this has to do with the HTML on the website and the way I'm scraping it, not the method you have suggested. Thank you again.